# using row deleting in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

so here i"m trying to use some delete function for my datagridview, here's the code behind:

```
 protected void gvTransaction_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        logID = Helper.GetLogID();
        try
        {
            LKLog.Write(logID, "Transaction.aspx.cs", "gvTransaction_RowDeleting", "Start Method", string.Empty, Helper.GetUserName());

            GridViewRow row = gvTransaction.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            orgID = CommonFunctions.StringToInt(gvTransaction.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());
            siteID = CommonFunctions.StringToInt(gvTransaction.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString());
            int transactionID = CommonFunctions.StringToInt(gvTransaction.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[2].ToString());
            clsTransaction.DeleteTransaction(logID, orgID, siteID, transactionID, true);

            string message = string.Format(Constants.DeleteMessage, "Transaction");
            LKLog.Write(logID, "Transaction.aspx.cs", "gvTransaction_RowDeleting", "End Method", string.Empty, Helper.GetUserName());
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Info", "alert('" + message + "');window.location ='Transaction.aspx';", true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LKLog.Write(logID, "Transaction.aspx.cs", "gvTransaction_RowDeleting", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message, Helper.GetUserName());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

here's the class function:

```
        public static void DeleteTransaction(decimal logID, int orgID, int siteID, int TransactionID, bool isActive)
    {
        LKLog.Write(logID, "clsTransaction.cs", "DeleteTransaction", "Start Method", string.Empty, Helper.GetUserName());
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CommonFunctions.GetAppDBConnection(Constants.AppID, Constants.TMDDBConnection)))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "spMSTransaction_Delete";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("OrgID", orgID));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("SiteID", siteID));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("TransactionID", TransactionID));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("IsActive", siteID));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Username", Helper.GetUserName()));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LKLog.Write(logID, "clsTransaction.cs", "DeleteTransaction", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message, Helper.GetUserName());
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        LKLog.Write(logID, "clsTransaction.cs", "DeleteTransaction", "End Method", string.Empty, Helper.GetUserName());
    }
```

the problem is, the code's not working (the row is not deleted, it just stay the same) is there any mistake or wrong-practice in using the code? thank you for your help

EDIT
the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spMSTransaction_Delete] 
@OrgID int,
@SiteID int,
@TransactionID int,
@IsActive bit,
@Username varchar(50)
 AS 
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  SET XACT_ABORT ON  

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE  [dbo].[MSTransaction]
SET     [IsActive] = @IsActive, 
        [ModifiedDate] = GETUTCDATE(), 
        [ModifiedBy] = @Username
WHERE   [OrgID] = @OrgID
        AND [SiteID] = @SiteID
        AND [TransactionID] = @TransactionID

COMMIT
```

Comment: What exactly does not work for you? Exception is throw? Row is not deleted from database? Anything else?

Comment: "The code's not working" is a useless statement when asking for help.  What is doing?  Are you seeing errors?  Anything?

Comment: i've edited the question, the problem is the row is not deleted from the database, sorry for misinformation

Comment: Can you provide and the store procedure?

Comment: what is passed in transactionID???all parameters are passed to the procedure correctlyt with proper datatype???

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? Are there any exceptions thrown at any point? Are the parameters passed correctly. If you manually execute the stored procedure from the database with the same parameters does the record get deleted then? Try and narrow down where the problem might be originating from.

Comment: @kostasch. i edited the question, hope it helps

Comment: @Anuj the transactionID pass integer value, is that what you mean?

Comment: all your 5 parameters are passed properly to the storedprocedure??did u debug and check???

Comment: As @Ben said, try to run the query in sql.

Comment: @Ben yes, i have already debugging the code, the parameter passed correctly, and yes the stored procedure manually works

Comment: where do u stuck then?any exception is shown???

Comment: Are you sure that the connection string is for the database you want? Maybe is for a test db.

Comment: @Anuj i stuck at deleting the row in the aspx page, it still show up, but when i delete manually from the database, it works, so i figured that there's an error in my code.

Comment: @kostasch. yes, i'm sure, because i can do insert function just fine

Comment: When you run c# code the record deletes from database? i have understand that not. I am i right?

Comment: @kostasch. the records stay still sir, no change at all until i manually delete it using stored procedure from the database

Comment: I think @Ben's solution may helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DeleteTransaction function

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("IsActive", siteID));
```

should this be something like

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("IsActive", isActive));
```

Perhaps you shouldn't even pass this from the code. Just set IsActive to false directly in your stored procedure since you'll always want to set it to false when you call this stored procedure.

Try changing your stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spMSTransaction_Delete] 
@OrgID int,
@SiteID int,
@TransactionID int,
@IsActive bit,
@Username varchar(50)
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET XACT_ABORT ON  

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE  [dbo].[MSTransaction]
SET     [IsActive] = 0, 
    [ModifiedDate] = GETUTCDATE(), 
    [ModifiedBy] = @Username
WHERE   [OrgID] = @OrgID
    AND [SiteID] = @SiteID
    AND [TransactionID] = @TransactionID

COMMIT
```

Comment: it shows error like this **Procedure or function 'spMSTransaction_Delete' expects parameter '@IsActive', which was not supplied.** and the `throw` code is marked red, when i do your solution

Comment: it shows no error, but the row still not deleting, anything else? :(

Comment: On my opinion, proc in IsActive should not have 0 but the parameter. Just to be more correct. :)

Comment: Ok what did you change exactly the code or stored procedure or both? @AbieGiordano

Comment: i took the advice from @kostasch. to set both to IsActive, and it worked, but still, i took your answer though so i vote it